# Unknown Property Error When Invoking object properties with in Apex:repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, repeat

I have an apex component which displays a list of Albums and Images under each album.

Here is the code for the component

```
global class AttachmentModel {
public ID Id;
public DateTime CreatedDate;
public String FileName;
public String Description;
public String ParentId;
public String ActualSizeExId;
public String FullSizeExId;
public String ThumbnailExId;
public String FullSizeUrl;
public String ThumbnailUrl;
public Decimal FileSize;
public String FileType; 
 }


<apex:component >
<apex:attribute name="albums" description="" type="Album__c[]" required="true" />
<apex:attribute name="images" description="" type="map" required="true" />
<apex:pageBlock>    
    <div class="content-section">
        <apex:repeat value="{!albums}" var="album">            
            <apex:repeat value="{!images[album.id]}" var="image">    
                    <div class="photo-item-container">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!album.name}"/>                               
                        <apex:image value="{!image.ThumbnailUrl}" width="200" height="200" />
                        <apex:outputText value="{!image.FileName}"/>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!image.Description}"/>
                    </div>
               </apex:repeat>            
        </apex:repeat>
    </div>
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:component>
```

- Attribute 'albums' is pass in as List === a list of Sobject 'Album__c'
- Attribute 'images' is pass in as Map> === a map of 'Album' Id and its Attachment(Image) list. Note that AttachmentModel is a custom model class I created in apex. the Code is posted above.

The problem is that Every time when this component is invoke, system throw error:
Unknown Property: ournamespace.AttachmentModel.ThumbnailUrl

It seems like the system can recognize the datamodel type but fail to recognize the properties under it.

Need your help to figure out why.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that you need a getter on each of the properties of your sub-class.

```
global class AttachmentModel {
     public ID Id { get; private set; }
     public DateTime CreatedDate { get; private set; }
     public String FileName { get; private set; }
     public String Description { get; private set; }
     public String ParentId { get; private set; }
     public String ActualSizeExId { get; private set; }
     public String FullSizeExId { get; private set; }
     public String ThumbnailExId { get; private set; }
     public String FullSizeUrl { get; private set; }
     public String ThumbnailUrl { get; private set; }
     public Decimal FileSize { get; private set; }
     public String FileType { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: greenstork, why we need getter setter for the sub-class? Also, why it has been set as private for set? Please help me to understand.

Comment: The private set means that you are only able to set the variable from within your code. Public is needed to accept a user input from a Visualforce page.